# JQuery ScrollTop works but only temporarily?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a chat app and want an infinitely scrolling div for the messages.

I have this line of jQuery:

```
$(".chatWindow").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).height() }, "slow");
```

I call it when I add a new message to the chat window and it causes it to perform a nice scroll to the bottom of the window... for the first few messages. After the first few messages it stops functioning and only scrolls to the same message after that.

Here is a demo so you can see the full implementation:

http://fireowldesigns.com/351/mainpage.html

It's not hooked up to the back end yet so call the following function to add a message

```
loadMessages("username", "message", "time")
```

Comment: your demo url is wrong, is missing the .tld

Comment: @Davebra whoops, been fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the .chatWindow with a fixed height of 80%, jQuery will always read that as 80% of its parent. If you try to console log `$(".chatWindow").height()` you'll se that is always the same value, no matter how long the div is.

One simple solution is to remove the fixed height and the overflow scroll from .chatWindow, wrap it into another container and change the scroll function. Here the example:

```
<div class="chatWindowWrapper">
    <div class="chatWindow">
        ...
    </div>
</div>


.chatWindowWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.chatWindow{
    width: 100%;
}


$(".chatWindowWrapper").animate({ scrollTop: $(".chatWindow").height() }, "slow");
```

Comment: Or use `scrollHeight`.

Comment: @Davebra that actually makes a lot of sense. For some reason I thought for sure I had to style the height on that specific div. Thanks for your help.